# react-native running tutorial 'AwesomeProject' on Android results in 'Unable to download JS Bundle' red screen

Tags: android, android-emulator, reactjs, react-native

I am following [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html#content) Facebook tutorial, and when running `react-native run-android` from AwesomeProject dir, I am getting a red screen on the android emulator, with the following text:

> Unable to download JS bundle. Did you forget to start the development server or connect your device?
>   **onResponse**
>   DevServerHelper.java:175
>   **run**
>   NamedRunnable.java:33
>   **runWorker**
>   ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113
>   **run**
>   ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588
>   **run**
>   Thread.java:818

I don't know if it's related, but I'm also getting a bunch of SyntaxErrors on the server regarding `const` not being valid in `strict mode` (I did not change anything in the original code) and getting the following error on START:

> < START> request:/index.android.bundle?platform=android
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of null
>           at /Users/tome/projects/reactNative/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/crawlers/index.js:16:84
>       at tryCallOne (/Users/tome/projects/reactNative/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
>       at /Users/tome/projects/reactNative/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:103:15
>       at flush (/Users/tome/projects/reactNative/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)

**Update**
Upgrading to Node v4.1.1 got rid of the `const` syntax error, but I still get the same result with the following error on React Packager:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of null
>       at /Users/tome/projects/reactNative/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/crawlers/index.js:16:84
>       at tryCallOne (/Users/tome/projects/reactNative/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
>       at /Users/tome/projects/reactNative/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:103:15
>       at flush (/Users/tome/projects/reactNative/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
>   [5:02:20 PM]  request:/index.android.bundle?platform=android
>   [5:02:20 PM]  find dependencies
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of null
>       at /Users/tome/projects/reactNative/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/crawlers/index.js:16:84
>       at tryCallOne (/Users/tome/projects/reactNative/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
>       at /Users/tome/projects/reactNative/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:103:15
>       at flush (/Users/tome/projects/reactNative/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
>   [5:02:26 PM]  request:/index.android.bundle?platform=android

Answer (score 4):

I managed to solve the issue. To anyone else who encounters the issue, re-installing watchman did the trick for me:
`brew uninstall watchman`
`brew install watchman`

My app is now running

Answer (score 0):

Also, I tried the Wathman install/uninstall route, with not much luck. What *did* work was making sure I updated and changed the version of node as used by *nvm*.

e.g. `nvm install 4.1.1`